# cant post data with retrofit using multipart when including file

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, multipart

i try use multipart for post data using retrofit android studio, but i have a problem, when i include the image file in `Call<ResponeBody>`, it nothing happent, but when i set the image file to `null`, its normaly upload to the server database

here is my code 
ApiInterface

```
@Multipart
@POST("booking-order")
Call<ResponseBody> bookingOrder(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> stringStringMap,
                                @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> stringBody,
                                @Part MultipartBody.Part filePart
);
```

`getImageFrom` phone storage

```
private void openFileChooser() {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

`getImage` uri

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mImageUri = data.getData();
    }
}
```

proceess

```
private void initProsesOrder(int ids) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("APP_TOKEN", UtilsApi.APP_TOKEN);
        map.put("USER_TOKEN", prefManager.getTokenUser());
        Map<String, RequestBody> bodyMap = new HashMap<>();
        bodyMap.put("member_id", createPartFromString(prefManager.getId() + ""));
        bodyMap.put("product_jasa_id", createPartFromString(ids + ""));
        bodyMap.put("member_address_id", createPartFromString(lokasi_maps));


        File file = new File(mImageUri.getPath());
        RequestBody propertyImage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/from-data"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part propertyImagePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("booking_image[]",
                file.getName(),
                propertyImage);


        Call<ResponeBody> call = apiInterface.bookingOrder(map,
                bodyMap,
                propertyImagePart);
        )
```

Comment: There must be an error in your client part or server. Please log the error inside `onFailure()` method with `Log.e("ERROR", t);` and [edit] your question, post the error logs here.

Comment: ohh man, thank for helping, problem solved. i dont know where can i check the error haha,